# How to export unequal length variables from R to an excel sheet?

Tags: r, excel, merge, r-xlsx, vba

I have two data frames in R as follows.

```
Team1 = c("a","b")
Grade1 = c(90,85)
DB1 = data.frame(Team1, Grade1)

Team2 = c("a","x","b")
Grade2 = c(79,92,85)
DB2 = data.frame(Team2, Grade2)
```

I want these four variables to be exported to a single excel sheet where the four columns should be '*Team1*','*Grade1*', '*Team2*' and '*Grade2*'.

I used to export data frames to excel sheets using **write.xlsx()** function but the problem here is, variables are not equal in lengths. Same happens when I try to **cbind()** variables and export to excel.

Is there any way that I can export these four variables to an excel sheet without worrying about their lengths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is `cbind.fill` to column bind the two datasets and it will fill the additional rows with `NA`

```
library(rowr)
DB12 <- cbind.fill(DB1, DB2, fill = NA)
DB12
#   Team1 Grade1 Team2 Grade2
#1     a     90     a     79
#2     b     85     x     92
#3  <NA>   <NA>     b     85
```

Comment: Used the command cbind.fill(DB1, DB2, fill = "") and it gave me the exact result I needed.